# What content of the Outer Rim DLC can be accessed without buying the season pass?

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2015

I really want to play the Outer Rim, and get all the weapons that come with it, but I don't want to pay fifty dollars for the season pass to get the DLC. Do I absolutely need to get the season pass to play the DLC?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to buy the season pass to get the Outer Rim DLC. Those with season pass get it early (which is why you see people playing it now), and the release date for those without the season pass is [April 5th](http://starwars.ea.com/starwars/battlefront/season-pass). You won't see the Outer Rim DLC by itself in any content distribution services until the April 5th release date.